# Grow RAID5 array

Tags: centos, raid, software-raid

I had a RAID5 volume in Centos7, the number of disks were 3 in the array. Now I am trying to grow the RAID5 volume with additional 1 disk but getting error while growing the RAID5 volume.

Command:

```
# mdadm --grow /dev/md0 --level=5 -n 4

mdadm: Need to backup 3072K of critical section..  
mdadm: Cannot start reshape for /dev/md0  
unfreeze
```

Comment: `dmesg`? `mdadm --examine /dev/sd?1`? Which mdadm version and try to build the latest one from git regardless. You could also crank up the `/sys/block/md0/md/stripe_cache_size` to `2048` or more. Maybe try a `--backup-file` too (make sure not to lose it so put it on a disk but not on the md0 itself)

Comment: Frostschutz, Thanks for your help, 
It worked after updating the mdadm version to v3.3.4

Thanks, 
Sourav Maity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked after updating the mdadm version to v3.3.4.

Thanks to Frostschutz.